# unclear about __bss_end and _start in the source

Tags: c, u-boot

For updating mon_len in the global data following statement was used in the u-boot source. Can you help to understand where __bss_end and  _start are defined?

```
gd->mon_len = (ulong)&__bss_end - (ulong)_start;
```

Comment: Have you looked at the *linker script file*? Have you tried to search *all* the files in the project?

Comment: I could see `ENTRY(_start)` and `KEEP(*(.__bss_end));` in the u-boot.lds linker script. These(_start, __bss_end) will be created as variables? if so, where these variables will be created in the final image file?

Comment: They're **not** variables. They're **symbols**.

Comment: ok, so during linking time the symbol offset will be used to calculate the size.